# How to get the date from a datepicker inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-datepicker

I have a ListView that consists out of 2 different item row types which are populated through a custom adapter. The first row type is a simple CheckedTextView, the second row type is a layout containing two datepickers
(the latter is only used for the last listView row).

When clicking a button in my activity I need to get the dates from the Datepickers in the last list item. However, i can't figure out how.

This is my layout_file for the datepicker (list_item_datepicker.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="vertical">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePickerFrom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"/>

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePickerTo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the getView methof of my adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
                viewHolder.title = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checked_textview);
                break;
            case TYPE_DATEPICKER:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_datepicker, null);
                viewHolder.datepickerFrom = (DatePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datePickerFrom);
                viewHolder.datepickerTo = (DatePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datePickerTo);
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            viewHolder.title.setText(items.get(position));
            viewHolder.title.setChecked(position == checked);
            break;
        case TYPE_DATEPICKER:
            break;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Where can I access the methods like getMonth() or getYear() of the datepicker class?

Thanks for any help.

**--------EDIT------------**
Sorry for not explaining myself clearly. I know that I can use the Datepicker methods like getMonth() or getYear() within the adapter's getView() method (in my case this would be below "case TYPE_DATEPICKER:"). 
However, this does not allow to respond to user input in realtime, i.e. the getMonth()/getYear()/... methods will only fire after doing some changes to the listview that cause the getView() method to be called again (e.g. scrolling). This is not sufficient in my case since the user does not need to scroll to apply the changes via the button (he can click a button in the Actionbar). In this case (without scrolling) I don't get the values from the datepickers. I need something like a "onDateChanged" listener which reacts right after the user changes the values of the datepickers. Any ideas?

Comment: "I need to get the dates from the Datepickers in the last list item" is that the last one shown on the screen or the last one in the list? The two are not the same if the list scrolls off the screen.

Comment: You can access method under case `Type_Datepicker`

Comment: It is the last one in the list

Comment: @DevendraDagur Sorry I think I didn't quite explain myself correctly. Yes, I can access getYear() and getDate() below case TYPE_DATEPICKER, However this gives me just the initial Datepicker values and doesn't listen correctly to change events. The dates are updated only after doing some changes to the list (e.g. scrolling) since only then getView() is called again. How can I get the new Date values immediately after the user changes them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Please see my edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use an onDateChangedListener on the datepickers.
Create a new class that implements the OnDateChangedListener interface:

```
public class MyOnDateChangedListener implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        String tag = view.getTag().toString();
        int mon = month + 1;

        String date = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;

        if (tag.equals("FROM")) {
            // do something for the datepickerFrom
        } else if (tag.equals("TO")) {
            // do something for the datepickerTo
        }
    }
}
```

And then, within the getView() method that inflates your datepicker, create a new instance of that class and init the datepickers:

```
 case TYPE_DATEPICKER:
                MyOnDateChangedListener fromDateChangedListener = new MyOnDateChangedListener();
                MyOnDateChangedListener toDateChangedListener = new MyOnDateChangedListener();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                  
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_datepicker, null);

                viewHolder.datepickerFrom = (DatePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datePickerFrom);
                viewHolder.datepickerFrom.setTag("FROM");
                viewHolder.datepickerFrom.init(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1, cal.get
                            (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), fromDateChangedListener);

                viewHolder.datepickerTo = (DatePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datePickerTo);
                    viewHolder.datepickerTo.setTag("TO");
                viewHolder.datepickerTo.init(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar
                        .DAY_OF_MONTH), toDateChangedListener);
                break;
```

To use the listener class with more than one datepicker (like in my case), you can set tags on the datepickers in the getView() method and then read out the tag in the onDateChanged() method in the listener class.